# How do I pass one type to a generic defined with two types in Rust?

Tags: rust

Supposing I have a function like this:

```
fn my<T: fmt::Debug, U>(x: T) {
    println!("{:?}", mem::size_of::<U>());
    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

It depends on two types `T` and `U`. I have to specify the type `U` when I call the function `my`. On the other hand, the type `T` can be determined from passed x, so, it's logical, I can miss it in a call.

When I try:

```
my::<u8>(10);
```

I get the error:

```
error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 2, found 1
```

What is the correct way to say to Rust compiler to get the type `T` from passed `x` and to pass `U` only in `<...>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rust, `_` in a type position is used to ask the compiler to infer something:

```rust
let foo: Vec<_> = (1..10).map(|i| i.to_string()).collect();
//           ^ collect in a vector whose type should be obvious
```

This also works in your case:

```rust
my::<_, u8>(10);
//   ^ infer `T`
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3c462d618de4fcc119e60f36205cf24f))